# How to change ref.current.children with useRef?

Tags: react-native

I wanted to change the content of the ref.current.children with ref.

Just like this:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyApp = () => {
  const aRef = useRef();
  useEffect(()=> {
    const node =aRef.current;
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Here I wanted to change the content of <Text> to 'Edited' but nothing happened.
      node.children = React.Children.map(node.children, (child) => {
        React.cloneElement(child, {}, 'Edited')
      })
    }, 1000)
  }, [])

  return (  
    <View ref={aRef}>  
      <Text>to be edited 1</Text> 
      <Text>to be edited 2</Text> 
    </View>
  );
}
```

What I got:

```
to be edited 1
to be edited 2
```

What I wanted:

```
Edited
Edited
```

Is there a way to get what I wanted?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use a ref and not a state?

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to learn react-native by doing my first project: a slot machine. 
And I found this project(https://github.com/latebachelor/html5-slot-machine) which I think is a cool way to make a slot.
It's a web slot, so it can use getElementById to access the DOM. And i want to imitate it in react-native. 
I just thought if i simply use ref in react-native, the imitating work would be easy and smooth.
Maybe i really should try state first before i post this question. I will try it later.
Any new suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: refs dont trigger a re-render so I think you would want to try useState